# separate the single file into many based upon a column value

Tags: bash, shell, awk

i have a file like this:

```
one vijay   three
two vijay   four
five chandu three
```

outputfile1

```
one vijay   three
two vijay   four
```

outputfile2

```
five chandu three
```

the file is split based upon the value of the second column.

i can do this in shell scripting.but i suppose its more simple in awk to do.
how do i do it in awk?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
awk '{print $0>$2".txt"}' file
```